# How do i make a discord bot receive text after a command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to become a fake discord bot, so i can use: `!!send` or something like that.
I have the token ready and i tried some repl.it templates but i have no idea of what to do.
here is the code i tried:

```
import discord
import os
import time
import discord.ext
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions,  CheckFailure, check
os.environ["TOKEN"] = "no-token-for-you-to-see-here"
#^ basic imports for other features of discord.py and python ^

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!') #put your own prefix here

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot online") #will print "bot online" in the console when the bot is online
    
    
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def send(ctx,*,message):
    await client.say(message)

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN")) #get your bot token and create a key named `TOKEN` to the secrets panel then paste your bot token as the value. 
#to keep your bot from shutting down use https://uptimerobot.com then create a https:// monitor and put the link to the website that appewars when you run this repl in the monitor and it will keep your bot alive by pinging the flask server
#enjoy!
```

It was online, but the command didn't work.

Comment: Hey there! Do you have any [minimum, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you could show us? We cannot give you the answer without seeing something you have tried first. Do visit [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further assistance. Have a good one!

Comment: @Bagle Okay, i put the code that i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `send` should be

```py
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, *, message: str):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Also, you're defining two `client(s)`. You need only one.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!!')
```

You're also importing some useless modules that you don't need right now.

Your final code should look like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is online")

@client.command()
async def send(ctx, *, message: str):
    await ctx.send(message)

client.run("token-of-the-bot")
```

Please tell me if it works or not. Have a great day :)

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you, now i can trick my friends into thinking that i made the best bot ever!

Comment: Glad it worked. Also please check my answer as accepted so it can help other users.

Comment: oh, i forgot, well now it's checked.